# Odoo 9 datepicker format

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

Format in datepicker is 10/17/2016 , how change to 17.10.2016

In qweb I use `t-field-options='{"format": "dd.MM.yyyy"}'`

what use in .xml view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Active debug mode in Odoo.

Now go to `Settings => Translations => Languages`

Select your current logged User language and update *Date Format* as per your requirement.

Reference:

[image: Date Format]